# Morris line graph date refuses to coerce to string in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, morris.js

I'm trying to make the date to a string which is usually using a simple

```
date.to_s
```

but it's not working I tried using Javascript string coercion.

```
String(date)
```

but this just gave me years. This is my code.

```
<script>
    Morris.Line({
  element: 'line',
  data: [
  <% metrics_history(current_user.oauth_token, 'page_impressions', 30).each do |k,v|%>
    { date: String(<%= k%>) , value: <%= v %>},
  <% end %>
  ],
  xkey: 'date',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['Value'],
  parseTime: false
});
</script>
```

This is what it returns.
[image]

Totally stuck here.

Data looks like this in the browser

```
Morris.Line({
                              element: 'line',
                              data: [
                                { date: String(2015-06-18) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-06-19) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-06-20) , value: 1},
                                { date: String(2015-06-21) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-06-22) , value: 23},
                                { date: String(2015-06-23) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-06-24) , value: 11},
                                { date: String(2015-06-25) , value: 1},
                                { date: String(2015-06-26) , value: 36},
                                { date: String(2015-06-27) , value: 41},
                                { date: String(2015-06-28) , value: 1},
                                { date: String(2015-06-29) , value: 11},
                                { date: String(2015-06-30) , value: 44},
                                { date: String(2015-07-01) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-07-02) , value: 35},
                                { date: String(2015-07-03) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-07-04) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-07-05) , value: 26},
                                { date: String(2015-07-06) , value: 68},
                                { date: String(2015-07-07) , value: 88},
                                { date: String(2015-07-08) , value: 10},
                                { date: String(2015-07-09) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-07-10) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-07-11) , value: 201},
                                { date: String(2015-07-12) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-07-13) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-07-14) , value: 10},
                                { date: String(2015-07-15) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-07-16) , value: 0},
                                { date: String(2015-07-17) , value: 0},
                              ],
                              xkey: 'date',
                              ykeys: ['value'],
                              labels: ['Value'],
                              parseTime: false
                            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the dates are not in quotes, Javascript sees them as integers and so does subtraction between the year and month and date. In your template, put quotes around date:

```
 <% metrics_history(current_user.oauth_token, 'page_impressions', 30).each do |k,v|%>
{ date: "<%= k%>" , value: <%= v %>},
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
{ date: '<%= raw k%>' , value: <%= v %>}
```